# Curl and Python Requests (get) reporting different http status code

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I have written a python script to validate url connectivity from a host.  What is reporting successful (http 200) in linux `curl` is reported as a 403 in the python (3.6) `requests` module.

I'm hoping someone can help me understand the differences here in reported http status codes?

Curl from the Linux command line....

```
$ curl -ILs https://www.h2o.ai|egrep ^HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Python requests module.....

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.h2o.ai'
>>> r = requests.get(url, verify=True, timeout=3)
>>> r.status_code
403
>>> requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
>>> r = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=3)
>>> r.status_code
403
```

Comment: What headers are you sending? What headers are you receiving? The reason for the 403 is probably explained in more detail in the body.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems the `python-requests/<version>` `User-Agent`is being served the 403 response from the site:

```
In [98]: requests.head('https://www.h2o.ai', headers={'User-Agent': 'Foo bar'})
Out[98]: <Response [200]>

In [99]: requests.head('https://www.h2o.ai')
Out[99]: <Response [403]>
```

You can contact the site owner if you want or just use a different user-agent via the `User-Agent` header (like i used above).

---

**How did i debug this:**

I have run `curl` with `-v` (`--verbose`) option to check the headers being sent, and then checked out the same with `requests` using `response.request` (assuming the response is saved as `response`).

I did not find any significant difference apart from the `User-Agent` header; hence, changing the `User-Agent` header worked as i expected.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  Would you mind sharing a little background on how you reached the conclusion that: "User-Agent is being served the 403 response from the site".  E.g. if I was troubleshooting, how would I know that this dummy header was the thing that h2o.ai was expecting?

Comment: This response and (especially) the update is a thing of beauty.  Thank you!