# Node `https.get` returns 403, `axios.get` and `curl` return 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to perform a GET request using Node's native `https` module and a 3rd party `axios` module (which is pretty commonly used):

```
const endpoint = 'https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/data/stats';

require('axios')
    .get(endpoint)
    .then(response => console.log('axios', response.status));
// prints 200

require('https')
    .get(endpoint, {},
        response => console.log('https', response.statusCode));
// prints 403
```

The `axios` request works fine as expected; I can view `response.data` as well.
But the `https` request fails with a 403.

- Strangely, both used to work last time I checked a few months ago.
- I haven't updated Node on my machine (node v 14.5.0). I've also tried on another machine as well (13.3.0).
- `curl` from the command line also works fine.

Since `https` used to work, my hunch is that the server must have changed something, and that `https.get` and `axios.get` must be doing something slightly differently (e.g. sending different headers by default) that the server is no longer indifferent to.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the two? I.E. first `https` then `axios`?

Comment: same thing. I've actually been trying them independently, I just combined them to make the snippet show that I'm doing the exact same thing otherwise.

Comment: Ok, interesting. I thought the server could have been rate-limiting your requests or something similar.

Comment: I think your hunch is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a little bit of testing, I noticed that by default the `https` module does *not* include an `User-Agent` header, while `axios` and `curl` both do. The server is rejecting your request because you have no `User-Agent` set.

To solve this, simply specify a custom `User-Agent` of your choice:

```
require('https')
    .get(endpoint, {headers: {'User-Agent': 'whatever'}},
        response => console.log('https', response.statusCode));
```

Answer (score 3):

After few web results focusing on node https didn't find an answer, I found another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268405/curl-and-python-requests-get-reporting-different-http-status-code) about python gets returning 403 while curl returns 200.

It turns out it was an issue with the request's `'User-Agent'` header.

Curl by default sends the user agent `'curl/7.72.0'`:

```
> GET /94548/2401383/manifest.js HTTP/1.1
> Host: cdn.flashtalking.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.72.0
> Accept: */*
```

Axios by default sends the user agent `'axios/0.20.0\r\n'`:

```
_header: 'GET /api/trade/data/stats HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.20.0\r\n' +
      'Host: www.pathofexile.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
```

While node's https by default sends no user agent:

```
  _header: 'GET /api/trade/data/stats HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Host: www.pathofexile.com\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
```

Apparently, the server now checks for a non empty `User-Aagent` header. Updating the https request to do so gets a 200:

```
const endpoint = 'https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/data/stats';

require('axios')
    .get(endpoint)
    .then(response => console.log('axios', response.status));
// prints 200

require('https')
    .get(endpoint, {},
        response => console.log('https', response.statusCode));
// prints 403


require('https')
    .get(endpoint, {header: {headers: {'User-Agent': '_'}}}},
        response => console.log('https', response.statusCode));
// prints 200
```