# CURL returns a successful response, but "requests" - 403

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, akamai

I am sending some request. Using curl - I successfully get the response (400 code). But by converting this request to python requests - I get only 403.

CURL:

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'authorization: Basic aXBob25lOmc0Wmk5cTEw' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'x-ecg-ver: 1.16' --compressed -H 'x-acf-sensor-data: 1,a,tn/iCnSgxfilyTx4JJRbl1oDrcIEo6hShqzKq3YqUpqBsmjc/TKeXFVxx/h++fOV3+LI84usfPT2K1bJPyqqz4pHPKDJ/lDGV4q7NhhuNj5traJB2Weyw5uZ/WUmp2+16L8jXXxE2ZG0aMEctowGtTy3xqPu8hOdcpN6eLuwYDw=,BYU5CQaztQ89Y3OUxXlOv7bufvUHZF5zjixWsPB/o7hrhtXhmDBYlN8IEtzPOxFxhyZdF2YJ4xnDU68FR2RnMUPIU6TGe5pXFJBeae/u+OqUeAoplzgGOpo6MudAMBUuyFImb4dSAR0jI3n46w9v/S2pp881uZoAK5XKSQgmN5c=$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$1000,2000,0' -H 'user-agent: Kleinanzeigen/14.16.5 (com.ebaykleinanzeigen.ebc; build:141525; Android 14.0.1) Alamofire/1.6.5' -X POST https://api.kleinanzeigen.de/api/account/resetpassword -d '{"email":"astapow.iw@ya.ru"}'
```

REQUESTS:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'authorization': 'Basic aXBob25lOmc0Wmk5cTEw',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'x-ecg-ver': '1.16',
    'x-acf-sensor-data': '1,a,tn/iCnSgxfilyTx4JJRbl1oDrcIEo6hShqzKq3YqUpqBsmjc/TKeXFVxx/h++fOV3+LI84usfPT2K1bJPyqqz4pHPKDJ/lDGV4q7NhhuNj5traJB2Weyw5uZ/WUmp2+16L8jXXxE2ZG0aMEctowGtTy3xqPu8hOdcpN6eLuwYDw=,BYU5CQaztQ89Y3OUxXlOv7bufvUHZF5zjixWsPB/o7hrhtXhmDBYlN8IEtzPOxFxhyZdF2YJ4xnDU68FR2RnMUPIU6TGe5pXFJBeae/u+OqUeAoplzgGOpo6MudAMBUuyFImb4dSAR0jI3n46w9v/S2pp881uZoAK5XKSQgmN5c=$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$1000,2000,0',
    'user-agent': 'Kleinanzeigen/14.16.5 (com.ebaykleinanzeigen.ebc; build:141525; Android 14.0.1) Alamofire/1.6.5',
}

json_data = {
    'email': 'astapow.iw@ya.ru',
}

response = requests.post('https://api.kleinanzeigen.de/api/account/resetpassword', headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

**sensor-data is constantly changing. One token is enough for 10 requests. It's definitely not the problem.**

I recorded a simple and clear video to prove my words:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcA9hZFwvR8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl and Python Requests (get) reporting different http status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268405/curl-and-python-requests-get-reporting-different-http-status-code)

Comment: @Rakib No. I convert curl to "requests" using an automatic converter. All headers, including user-agent, are specified in my request.